# Whenever I try to run my server via Heroku I get "Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv'"

Tags: node.js, typescript, heroku

Browsing stack overflow, I noticed that a common fix is make sure that dotenv is in dependencies and not just devDependencies. Here's a [screenshot of the log and the package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bsB6.png). You'll notice that dotenv is indeed in my dependencies. I also deleted and reinstalled node_modules multiple times but still no luck.

I am requiring the dotenv at the top of my server file [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RJTJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. I decided to try uninstalling dotenv and reinstalling, this worked. Apparently, this was different from deleting node modules and npm install.

Answer (score 0):

I see `dotenv` is added to a `devDependency`: [`devDependency`](https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file) are special and are only installed when you do a `npm install` on the `package.json` which contains them. Usually, you'll add your development tooling (like test runners, etc.) in `devDependencies` since they are not required for the application to run.

When we run an application in production, we install dependencies using `npm install --production` which only installs the dependencies mentioned in the `dependencies` section of `package.json`. This is also what Heroku does for you (check their buildpack for Node.js!)

To install a `devDependency`, you would do: `npm i -D <package name>`; and to install a production `dependency` (like your web framework like `express`), you'd do `npm i -S express`.

Try running `npm i -D dotenv` and check if it works (it may also work if you just do a `npm i dotenv`.